# Integral of $\int{\sqrt{x^2+a}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Give integral I = $\int{\sqrt{x^2+a}}dx$

---

Using the U substitution, solution of integral is as follows. 
u = $\sqrt{x^2+a}$ 
du= $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+a}}$
dv = dx
v = x

---

I am trying to understand how the give steps below have been simplified
I = $x\times\sqrt{x^2+a}$ -$\int{\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+a}}}dx$ = 
 = $x\times\sqrt{x^2+a}$ -$\int{\frac{(x^2+a)-a}{\sqrt{x^2+a}}}dx$=
= $x\times\sqrt{x^2+a}$ - $\int{\sqrt{x^2+a}}dx$
+ $a\times\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a}}}dx$=
 
= $x\times\sqrt{x^2+a}-I $  + $a\times\ln{|x+\sqrt{x^2+a}|}$

I was trying to make sense of following steps but i couldn't, how can we simplify the following part of integral from $\int{\frac{(x^2+a)-a}{\sqrt{x^2+a}}}dx$ to  $\int{\sqrt{x^2+a}}dx$ + $a\times\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a}}}dx$

Comment: Let $x=\sqrt a\tan(x)$ and see what happens.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Math-fun And if $a<0$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think the OP is using MathJax. Not quite the way you or I would, but they are trying quite hard IMHO.

Comment: The simplification you listed at the end of your question is incorrect. It should be:
$$\int \frac{(x^2+a)-a}{\sqrt{x^2+a}}~dx=\int \sqrt{x^2+a}~dx\color{red}{-}a\cdot \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a}}~dx$$

Comment: @projectilemotion i haven't done the simplification, it is taken from the book, i am trying to make sense... why you think that is wrong?

Comment: Your book is correct, however what you wrote at the end is incorrect.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I suppose you're right.

Comment: @projectilemotion i am trying to understand the steps made to break the integral in two parts. I know that solution is not correct at the end because it need little more algebra

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you, but does the $\tan$ substitution make a problem if $a<0$? (though OP could also use a hyperbolic substition) of course there other ways to tackle the problem ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget the negative sign in front of that integral. The simplification occurs like this:

$$-\int \frac{(x^2+a)-a}{\sqrt{x^2+a}}\;dx = -\int \left(\frac{x^2+a}{\sqrt{x^2+a}} - \frac{a}{\sqrt{x^2+a}}\right)\;dx = -\int \left(\sqrt{x^2+a} -
 \frac{a}{\sqrt{x^2+a}}\right)\;dx = -\int \sqrt{x^2 + a}\;dx + a\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a}}\;dx$$

Comment: I see what i have missed , simply by multiplying the first integral with $\frac{\sqrt{x^2+a}}{\sqrt{x^2+a}}$. i appreciate